# Using Redis variables as local session variables

Tags: php, laravel, redis

So my new portal project is running on `PHP` 7.2, using `Laravel` as the framework, and I'm wanting to use `Redis` as the Session Handler. I have it all set up and I thought everything was working correctly. I got the logins all setup and started some work on the main page when I asked someone to try logging in.

The setup is that when you login it saves a token to the database upon succession with a timer. Then I use `Redis::set('token', *token*)` and `Redis::set('token_exp', *date and time of exp*)` I know you can set tokens and stuff to automatically expire which I'll switch to after working on the project a bit more. But when the authentication method went to check and see if they were logged in, it saw the token for my log in.

I didn't realize that those weren't saving based on the session but rather publically. How do I make it so stuff set through `Redis` is only per session and not server-wide?

I could potentially use a key stored in $_SESSION to access the REDIS variables but I feel like that really defeats the purpose of using REDIS if I'm going to use $_SESSION anyway.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working with my answer below?

Comment: @atymic So I came to terms with the idea of using SESSION as I realized it was the only way to save "local" variables. But I decided I still want roughly everything else to save to Redis. So what I ended up doing was saving the username of the logged in user to SESSION and made any variables associated with that person set to Redis like so, "Redis::set($_SESSION->username . 'user_variable', $user_variable)" This works perfectly and then on logout I just have it empty any variables pertaining to that user. It works really well! Thank you for your reply though!

Answer (score 0):

`Redis` is a facade for the direct connection to the redis server. Any data stored using a `Redis::set` is simply set on the redis instance.

To set something on the session, you can use it's facade:

```php
\Session::put('token', 'xyz');
```

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#storing-data